# How can I install without a USB drive?

Tags: installation, windows, usb

How can I install Ubuntu Netbook Edition without ceating a USB drive? Can I have Windows and Ubuntu at the same time?

Comment: Maybe you should add in the topic that you're asking about Netbook Edition. I missed it and misread everything.

Answer (score 2):

Check this ones:

Easy way: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17486/install-ubuntu-netbook-remix-with-wubi-installer/

Harder: http://blog.crox.net/archives/54-Installing-Ubuntu-Netbook-Remix-over-the-network-UNR-netboot-PXE-install.html

Crazy: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9875937&postcount=10

Maybe one of the official methods (other than usb and optical drive) here: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/installation-guide/i386/install-methods.html can be useful for you.

Comment: I am guessing that he is asking how to do it without a USB drive is because he does not have a cd driver either... correct me if I am wrong... if that is the case, then the best bet is to go to your local department store, and pick up a cheap usb drive... I would recommend a 2gb sandisk cruzer, as it is cheap (about 10 US dollars) and I know that they are bootable... Of course you would have to use a program like unetbootin to get Ubuntu onto your flash drive.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have misunderstood everything. But I guess he can't boot from usb and that's why he's asking. So I have editted my answer to point to non-cd non-usb ways of installing it. There are probably quite a few more.